# How can I create a common python class method which returns mean and std dev for any function distribution?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have a function:

```
def f1(q, d):
    p1 = d['p1']
    p2 = d['p2']
    return p1*p2/q
```

q is a number, while d is dictionary which contains values for parameters 'p1' and 'p2'. These parameters have some uncertainties in them. For simplicity, let's assume both are normally distributed p1, p2 ~N[mean= 2.1, sigma= 0.4].
Now I want to create a class with methods for evaluating mean and std dev etc for calculated functions. So far, I have approached it in the following way:

```
import numpy as np

class Example:
    def __init__(self, function, *args, **kwargs):
        self.function = function

    def Dist_Property(N=100):
        _random_dict, random_dict = {}, {}
        for i in ['p1', 'p2']:
            _random_dict[i] = np.random.normal(2.1, 0.4, N)
        random_dict = [{k: v[j] for k, v in _random_dict.items()} for j in range(N)]
        a = np.array([self.function(*args, **kwargs) for d in adict])
        return {'m': a.mean(), 'std': a.std()}
```

(I have used *args, **kwargs because in future I will want to use the method for functions with varying no. of arguments.)
This code does not work when I call Dist_Property method.

```
y = Example(f1(q=2, d = {'p1': 2.1, 'p2': 2.1}))
print(y.Dist_Property())
```

Running this code gives NameError: name 'args' is not defined in np.array([self.function(*args, **kwargs) for d in random_dict]).

Can somebody please explain to me what is wrong with this code. I am a very recent learner of python so there might be some really stupid mistake I have done here. Sorry for a bit long question.

Comment: ‘Doesn’t work’ is too vague: please edit the __full__ error message into your question. However, `Example(f1(q=2, d = {'p1': 2.1, 'p2': 2.1}))` passes the result of calling f1 to Example. You need to pass `f1` like this: `y=Example(f1)` then self.function can be called, although you also have to provide the parameters.

Comment: @barney I am tnow rying y = Example(f1); print(y.Dist_Property()). But this gives NameError: name 'args' is not defined. I also don't know now how to pass argument 'q' in this setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added some context about arguments and keyword arguments before mentioning a solution. Google `args and kwargs in python` to find out more if you'd like.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(69) # for reproducability

def function(*arguments, **keywordArguments):
    print("Arguments:", arguments)
    print("Keyword arguments:", keywordArguments)
    print()


print("Args and kwargs here...")
function(1, 2, 3, hello=1, world=2)

def sayHelloAndCallFunction(functionToCall, *args, **kwargs):
    print("Hello there, have a good day!")
    functionToCall(*args, **kwargs)


# Notice that I haven't used function(...) below. I passed the function as an argument,
# the sayHelloAndCallFunction calls the function for us.
print("Passing function as argument!")
sayHelloAndCallFunction(function, 1, 2, 3, hello=1, world=2)


argsDict = {'p1':1, 'p2':2}

# ** is an operator that unpacks a dictionary
print("Unpacking dictionary")
function(**argsDict)

print("Without unpacking")
function(argsDict)


# The above is the context for what is perhaps what you want

def f1(*args, **kwargs):
    q = args[0]
    p1 = kwargs['p1']
    p2 = kwargs['p2']
    return p1*p2/q


class Example:
    def __init__(self, function, *args):
        self.function = function

        # you might want to pass only 'q' in the args variable
        self.args = args
        print("Arguments:", self.args)

    def distProperty(self, N=100):# you missed self variable here :)
        _random_dict, random_dict = {}, {}

        for i in ['p1', 'p2']:
            _random_dict[i] = np.random.normal(2.1, 0.4, N)

        random_dict = [{k: v[j] for k, v in _random_dict.items()} for j in range(N)]

        # here you use the dictionary to pass p1, p2 as keyword arguments
        a = np.array([self.function(*self.args, **d) for d in random_dict]) # assumed you meant random_dict here
        return {'m': a.mean(), 'std': a.std()}

q = 10

print("Calling init method")
obj = Example(f1, q)

print("Calling dist property")
p = obj.distProperty()
print("Output:", p)
```

The output will be:

```
Args and kwargs here...
Arguments: (1, 2, 3)
Keyword arguments: {'hello': 1, 'world': 2}

Passing function as argument!
Hello there, have a good day!
Arguments: (1, 2, 3)
Keyword arguments: {'hello': 1, 'world': 2}

Unpacking dictionary
Arguments: ()
Keyword arguments: {'p1': 1, 'p2': 2}

Without unpacking
Arguments: ({'p1': 1, 'p2': 2},)
Keyword arguments: {}

Calling init method
Arguments: (10,)
Calling dist property
Output: {'m': 0.43414417169935005, 'std': 0.126635092037423}
```

Please let me know if this is what you wanted :)

Comment: Actually, in my code, I have several function, say, f1(q, dict1), f2(q, p, dict1), f3(q, p, dict1, dict2). Only dict1 is used to generate random numbers.  I don't want to use *args, **kwargs notations in my function definitions; this will make me change the whole code. Is it possible in some way to define class method such that it works on all three functions? Thanks for the helpful answer, anyway. I understand logic much better now.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could describe what these functions have in common other than them taking a dictionary as an argument. I haven't understood what exactly you need. The functions f1, f2 .. etc need to have some common workflow that can be incorporated into the `distproperty` function

Comment: Your solution actually works, but what I don't want is writing all my functions f1, f2 etc in a the format you wrote, i.e. using *args, **kwargs. The common thing between all of functions is one dictionary (as argument), which is used to generate random distribution. There are other arguments in f1 and f2 as well but they may or may not be common to each other; but these arguments are constants, and should not concern DistProperty method. Sorry, if it is not clear yet. Anyways, I am accepting your answer now...I should be able to work my way out now. Thanks.

Comment: It is not at all necessary that you define `f1(*args, **kwargs)`. You can define `f(q, p1, p2)`, and assign of arguments `argsDict = {q:1, p1:2, p2:3}` within `Example.distProperty` and call `f1(**argsDict)`.